# intransitive verbs which become transitive if their "goal/purpose" is accomplished

Tags: transitivity

I've realized many verbs follow an interesting transitive pattern, which I illustrate with an example:

Webster's defines **wrangle** as either intransitive *dispute, argue* or transitive *to obtain by persistent arguing*.

Is there a grammar term for this behavior?

Comment: Could you give example sentences for both usages of 'wrangle' and for both usages of 3 or 4 other verbs exhibiting this behaviour, GLC? The first two T/I verbs I've thought of (teach // teach a class/a lesson/history  ////  play // play a game) don't fit into the 'goal attained' pattern.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _They wrangled (over) a commitment to peace out of the opposing side_, where the prep **over** makes the verb intransitive

Comment: Yes (They wrangled over a commitment to peace **with** the opposing side / They wrangled a commitment to peace out of the opposing side). Others?

Comment: Though it's an interesting question, I'm not sure "wrangle" is strictly one of the words as you describe them, at least according to some dictionaries. Collins Dictionary: "2. (tr) to encourage, persuade, or obtain by argument." "encourage" definitely doesn't mean success. Also "v.t. 2. to argue or dispute. 4. to obtain, often by badgering or scheming;" - both (2) and (4) are listed as trans. by the Random House dictionaries. Dictionaries such as Cambridge and Oxford (on Lexico) don't even list the successful transitive version of "wrangle".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Just out of curiosity, don't people say that phrases and clauses act as objects? In "They wrangled over a commitment to peace..." couldn't "over a commitment to peace" be seen as a prepositional phrase that's an object of "wrangle"? It's explained that way in a Wikipedia article that mentions "tritransitive verbs", where there are direct, indirect, and prepositional phrase objects. Or is the general dichotomy between trans. and intrans. based on the simpler rule of whether the verb takes either a direct or indirect object only?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  _They wrangled for hours to achieve a commitment to peace_

Comment: @Zebrafish Though there are those here on ELU who will come out with a virtually papal decree on this, I've come across various analyses / labellings by various grammarians. Aarts is perhaps the one who has done the most research on this, though I believe he's changed his stance in recent years. You can look up "direct object" here for previous discussions, though "the piano had a stool" might be a more fruitful string to search for.

Comment: That's wrangle again. You say this behaviour is shown by _many_  verbs. Please add a few more examples/

Comment: @EdwinAshworth French _accoucher_ in the intransitive sense means “to go into labour”, but in the transitive sense it signifies the result of the labour: “to deliver (a baby)”

Comment: Excuse me for nitpicking again, but French "accoucher" can be intransitive to mean to give birth, which is an act of completing something, or "success" as you put it. "Je devrais accoucher en mai. - I should give birth in May."  I'm not saying that can't mean "I should go into labor in May", but "to give birth" is still one of the meanings of the intransitive "accoucher", isn't it?

Comment: How is this any different than words that have multiple senses—or that can be used as a noun or a verb (or assume any number of other grammatical roles)? I don't see how one sense being intransitive and another sense being transitive is unique or particularly noteworthy. At least in relation to those other words that have multiple senses and functions.

Comment: I would say that _wrangle_ (and its ilk)  can be interpreted either as active or resultative, like _wiggle_ (_He wiggled the shoe with his foot/He wiggled the ball out of the grate_). This is akin to the use of some verbs as either inchoative or causative, like _get_.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a single term, but you're certainly not the first person to notice this phenomenon. Huddleston & Pullum (2002) have this to say in their discussion of transitive/intransitive contrasts (p. 304):

> With a considerable number of verbs the intransitive construction is characteristically used for an activity and the transitive one for an accomplishment. This is so, for example, with *I ironed* vs *I ironed your shirt*, *We read* vs *We read the report,* and so on.

In their terminology, an accomplishment, unlike an activity, has "inherent terminal point" (p. 120); note that neither term necessarily denotes something done by a human (or even an animate) being.

In "We read the report," the reading of the report has a defined endpoint, the point at which the whole report has been read. In "We read" (past tense), though, the amount being read is unspecified and there is no fixed endpoint.